# Why do I get no text alert for one contact only?

Tags: messages, notifications, sms, do-not-disturb

I have an iPhone 5s and when my mom texts it doesn't make a noise. It does when everyone else does.

There is a small gray moon next to her name, but I have checked and her phone is NOT on "Do not disturb". Any suggestions?

Comment: What you described is what we have except there is no gray moon. :(

Answer (score 6):

Your phone may not be on "Do Not Disturb," but that conversation is - it's a separate setting from your phone's "Do Not Disturb" setting.

Just go into that conversation -> Details -> toggle the Do Not Disturb switch and you should have your notifications back.

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem on the iPhone 7 after the iOS 11 update. Go to your message log and swipe left on that persons messages and then click show alerts.

Answer (score 2):

On your text screen, swipe to the left on the contact’s message. Reset to ‘show alerts’. The sound will be restored.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the iPhone 8. And mine did that too. If you to go their messages, there should be a on/off switch that says hide alerts. If the switch is green than tap it off so it turns gray.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my iPhone 5s I wasn’t getting any message tone alert from my husband’s messages he sent me and I also had a grey moon symbol next to his name .,I just  now went to his messages & there’s the information (ℹ️) symbol at the top on the right hand side just click on it & make sure you have the hide alerts off..Mine was on that’s why i wasn’t receiving his message alert tone.. once I turned it off the  grey moon symbol was removed I will test it tomorrow to make sure it works hopefully it will
Resolve your problem as well.